# Main.java instead of (project name)Application.java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have generated many projects with Spring Initializr and every time I try to import them into intellij I find that no one of them have (project name)Application.java as main, but Main.java instead, as you would have in a normal java project.

I tried to modify it into a normal Spring Boot main but intellij never recognizes the pertaining imports. None of the Maven lifecycle processes work either, as they only display errors related to the issue at hand.

What could be causing this and what could fix this? Is it something I need to fix on my IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you select

- Language - Java
- Project - Maven
- Spring Boot - 3.0.4
- Project medatadata -> Name -> ***`Test`***
- Packaging - Jar
- Java - 17

Generate

In your folder there will be a file since you added value in Name "Test"

demo\src\main\java\com\example\demo\TestApplication.java

I just tested it, it is working as expected.